# How to check whether value is in database without throwing an exception in Zend?

Tags: database, exception, zend-framework

I have a registration action in Zend controller and I want to ensure that given username isn't already in the database.

```
$tUser = $userMapper->getDbTable();
$select = $tUser->select()
                ->from(array('u'=>'users'))
                ->where('u.user_username = ' . $value);
$row = $tUser->fetchRow($select);
```

Unfortunately, this snippet of code throws the Exception **when i just want to check the $row is null or not and keep writing my code**.

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'admin' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT `u`.* FROM `users` AS `u` WHERE (u.user_username = admin) LIMIT 1

Should I remove the try/catch blocks in my controller or can I do it in another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by error description, I'd say it will throw an exception always, no matter if user exists or not, because bad SQL query will be generated. Try passing `$value` as second parameter to `where`, like this:

```
$tUser = $userMapper->getDbTable();
$select = $tUser->select()
                ->from(array('u'=>'users'))
                ->where('u.user_username = ?', $value);
$row = $tUser->fetchRow($select);
```

You will then check if user exists like this:

```
if(!$row) {
    // user doesn't exist
} else {
    // user exists
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. i must read the error messages more precisely ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    $tUser = $userMapper->getDbTable();
    $select = $tUser->select()
                ->from(array('u'=>'users'))
                ->where('u.user_username = ?', $value);
    $row = $tUser->fetchRow($select);
} catch (Zend_Db_Exception $e) {
   echo "<pre>";print_r($e);
}
```